# Cannot run executable (created by gcc) specified in Makefile in Windows 10

Tags: gcc, makefile, nasm

I am using Windows 10.

I have written a **nasm** assembly program and a **Makefile** to run that program in command prompt using `make` command.

**main2.asm:**

```
segment .text 
global main 
extern exit 
main: 
    push rbp 
    mov rbp, rsp 
    sub rsp, 32 ; shadow parameter space 
    mov ecx, 5 ; parameter for exit function 
    call exit
```

**Makefile:**

```
nasm:
     nasm -f win64 main2.asm -o main2.obj
     gcc main2.obj -o main2
     main2
     echo %errorlevel%
```

**Commands written in command prompt:**

```
make nasm
```

**Result of cmd:**

```
C:\**\Source Code\Assembly\New>make nasm
nasm -f win64 main2.asm -o main2.obj
gcc main2.obj -o main2
main2
make: main2: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:8: nasm] Error 127
```

`main2.exe` file was created successfully but I cannot run that **exe** file directly using **Makefile** in windows 10 (In linux, it works).

But if I write `main2` separately in cmd, then it runs well and can verify using `echo %errorlevel%` command.

How can i run executable (.exe) directly using Makefile (in windows 10) without having to write program name every time I run the program?

Comment: Does it work if you use `./main2` instead of just `main2`?

Comment: Try to add `.exe` to `main2`.

Comment: @MadScientist No it didn't work.

Comment: @ykaner Same case. It didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use windows so I can't help beyond that.